# Twitter/Reddit posts not embedding properly on Django template

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller, tweepy, praw

I'm building a news aggregator. I am connected to the twitter and reddit APIs through the tweepy and PRAW libraries. I'm pulling json data from twitter and reddit, and displaying posts in a timeline format side by side.

I have one template called main.html which takes in context(reddit post ids; twitter status urls) and passes that context to template tags, in order to generate html to embed. Here is the template where all this work is being done. The template tags are 'tweet_tags.py' and 'red_attempt.py' as you can see loaded at the top of the page.

```
{% block content %}{% load red_attempt %} {% load tweet_tags %} {% autoescape off %}
<h1>Welcome</h1>
<a href="/main" class="btn btn-danger">Refresh News</a>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <h3 class='text-center'>Reddit News</h3>
      {% for item in reddit %}
      <div class="mdl-card__media" id="timeline"></div>
        {% red_attempt item %}
      <br>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <h3 class='text-center'>Twitter News</h3>
      {% for item in twitter %}
      <div class="mdl-card__media" id="timeline"></div>
        {% tweet_tags item %}
      <br>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endautoescape %}{% endblock %}
```

The template tags are 'tweet_tags.py' and 'red_attempt.py' as you can see loaded at the top of the page.

Here is their code, respectively:

**tweet_tags.py**

```
def tweet_tags(url):  
    """ Requests a tweet from oembed and returns the html element """

    tweet_request = requests.get(
        'https://publish.twitter.com/oembed?url=' + url + '&omit_script=true')
    tweet_json = tweet_request.json()
    tweet_html = tweet_json['html']

    return tweet_html  # returns to our template
```

---

**red_attempt.py**

```
def red_attempt(url):  
    """ Requests a tweet from oembed and returns the html element """

    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'nba_comp app',
        'From': 'nickiscool88',
        'Accept': 'application/json'  
    }

    endpoint = requests.get(
        f"https://www.reddit.com/oembed?url=https://www.reddit.com{url}", headers=headers)

    return endpoint.json()['html']
```

---

This all works as expected.

What I want to do, is instead, have a services script pull the twitter and reddit data, *store that data in my database with models.py* then pull the data from the local database to display. I'm trying to do that in this script, **test.html**

```
{% block content %} {% autoescape off %}

{% for post in all %}
  <div class="mdl-card__media" id="timeline"></div>
  <p>{{ post.html }}</p>
</div>
{% endfor %} {% endautoescape %}{% endblock %}
```

In this case, "all" is the context, which is a database object from models.py. Here is my models.py script.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    post_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    root_url = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="", unique=True)
    html = models.TextField(default="")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

So as you can see, I'm trying to loop through all the posts in my database, and post the html of each post. I'm expecting the same result as main.html, but instead, it looks like this[image: test.html]

---

as opposed to main.html which looks like this

[image]

All the script/widget tags that support embedding are at the bottom of the HTML templates.

How can I display these twitter/reddit posts from my database in test.html similar to how I can display them like main.html, where I'm just fetching the json data?

Comment: Anyone? Not sure if this bumps the post

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved. The script tags used for embedding twitter/reddit posts needs to be inside the  tag.